# Angular: Observable with subscribe returns error 200 OK as the response is not JSON

Tags: json, angular, error-handling, async-await, observable

I am developing a front-end web application using Angular 11. This application uses several services which return data in JSON format.
I use the **async / await** javascript constructs and the **Observables** to get the answers from these services. This is an example my call:

```
let myResponse = await this.myService(this.myData);
myResponse.subscribe(
   res => {
    console.log("Res: ",res)
   }, (error) => {
    console.log("Error: ",error)
   }
);
```

where `this.myService` contains the code doing the HTTP call using Angular `httpClient`.
Unfortunately a specific service (only one!) doesn't return data in JSON format but it returns a **byte array** (string that identifies a pdf -format `application/pdf`-).
Unfortunately this invocation causes a very strange error with code 200 OK:

[image]
[image]

How can I do to prevent `res` from being interpreted as JSON and therefore this error being reported? How can I read `res`reporting that **it will not be in json format**?

This service has no errors (with Postman it works perfectly). The problem is Javascript and Observable which are interpreted as JSON. How can I read the content of `res` in this case?

Comment: Await is used for promises.. but your service returns an observable..? Not sure if that’s relevant, but it looks strange..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a HTTP API call is not returning a `JSON`, just provide the proper value in the `responseType` option:

```
this.httpClient.get('<URL>', {
      responseType: 'arraybuffer'
});
```

Ref: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#description